# Paper A that cited Paper B is found via GoogleScholar, yet the citation is not counted for Paper B. Why?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

As stated in the subject, Paper A that cited Paper B is found via GoogleScholar (as is paper B), yet the citation is not counted for Paper B. Can anybody offer some insight into how this can happen or why?
Note that the paper B was properly cited by paper A, via a citation export on one of the popular services.

Is this common? I thank you in advance.

Comment: GoogleScholar database take some time to update - up to 6 months at times.

Comment: @RanG. If I may ask a follow up. Is this true, even when both papers, A and B, are already found by google scholar (one can find either paper on GS)? Thank you in advance. (It is my first citation, which is why I am so invested in this :) )

Comment: In Google Scholar a citation appear as soon as the citing paper it is published/accepted and appeared online. In general it takes no more than 5 days.

Comment: Usually the citation count changes as soon as a new paper appears, but  sometimes it doesn't -especially when there is a previous version with the same title. I don't know how the algorithm works, but I have seen citation counts that increased by 10-30 in one day, and decreased by 1-10 few days later, without any clear explanation to this behaviour other than re-indexing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine that A cites B, Google Scholar parses the citation list at the end of paper A. There are a number of things that could go wrong there: bad OCR, use of ligatures in Latex, confusion between papers with the same title, a "references" section that Google does not identify as such...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, congratulations on your first citation! Similarly, my first paper had problems with Google Scholar, such as Google Scholar not finding it and when it did, it combined the citations with a few other papers. It eventually resolved itself about 6 months later (as others said).

So just be patient! Google Scholar will find it in time - I have found various papers citing my works but Google Scholar has not picked it up yet (though it is usually pretty good).